# Trying to create a chart in css with php data

Tags: html, css, charts

I've tried many many ways to do it but I can't.

Users have advertise on my website, and each time a visitor clicks on it, I save the event time into the database to make "mini stats" in user account.

For example, a user has an advertise and it's active 30 days.

The goal is to create a chart (in CSS) to show clicks per day (day1 = 2 clicks, day2 = 25 clicks, day3 = 64 clicks...)

This is how I get the clicks per days. I create an array with 30 indexes (duration days). I set each element value to 0. Then I check if given time ($time->click_time) correspond to the day.

```
<?php

// $data = results from sql query

$duration = 30; // Active days

$clicks_days = array();

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $duration; $i++ )
    $clicks_days[ $i ] = 0;

foreach ( $data as $time ) {

    if ( $time->click_time && $time->click_time > $start_time && $time->click_time < $expiry_time ) {

        $a = round( ( $expiry_time - $time->click_time ) / 24 / 60 / 60 );
        $day = $duration - $a;

        $clicks_days[ $day ] = $clicks_days[ $day ] + 1;

    }

}

?>
```

My array is ready to be treated:

```
Array (
    [1] => 12,
    [2] => 30,
    [3] => 64,
    ...
    [30] => 72,
)
```

Now with HTML and CSS, how can make a simple chart (view image below)?
Knowing that I want the chart with a certain fixed height (36px) and I'd like to calculate the height percent of each array element.

[image]

Hope my english is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this I would recommend using this JavaScript library: chartjs.org, you can use Ajax and JSON to parse data to it.

Comment: Using canvas means HTML5 only right?

Comment: Yes, but this is quite small and scaleable, I use chartjs and it is really good!

Comment: Works like a charm, you made my day! Thank you

Comment: Can you help more, I'm using WordPress and pass labels and values from PHP using wp_localize_script(), but the problem is that in JS it's like an object. Should I convert that object to an array? If so, how do I do? Thanks

Comment: Hey,

I would recommend looking at the Wordpress documentation, that should help you more. I hope this helps, not had much experience of programming with Wordpress to be honest.

Regards,

Richard.